# How to dispose OracleParameter objects?

Tags: c#, oracle, memory, garbage-collection

I have an application written in C# that interacts with an Oracle Database using Oracle.DataAccess.Client and is taking up a lot of memory. I ran CLR profiler on it and I see that most of the heap is occupied with OracleParameter objects.

I read a bit about the whole OracleCommand and OracleParameter classes, and i added disposal functions at the end of every try block that uses OracleParameters. I also tried disposing exactly as shown in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm#ODP) but it showed the same results.

Every function is somewhat like the following:

```cs
OracleCommand oraCmd = null;
            try
            {
                oraCmd = GetCommand();
                oraCmd.CommandText = "PKG_TASK_MGR." + commandName;
                oraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                oraCmd.Parameters.Add("retVal", OracleDbType.Int16, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                oraCmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_RESOURCE_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                oraCmd.Parameters["TASK_RESOURCE_ID"].Value = task.ResourceId;
                oraCmd.Parameters.Add("TASK_DATA", OracleDbType.XmlType, ParameterDirection.Input);
                oraCmd.Parameters["TASK_DATA"].Value = xmlData;
                oraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.CreateMessage(PkgID.TASK_MGR).Error("failed to update taskdata/additional data! error:{0}", ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                DisposeCommand(oraCmd);
            }
```

and the DisposeCommand is as follows:

```cs
private void DisposeCommand(OracleCommand oraCmd)
        {
            if (oraCmd == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (OracleParameter cmdParam in oraCmd.Parameters)
            {
                cmdParam.Dispose();
            }
            oraCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            oraCmd.Dispose();
        }
```

I expected there to be a lot less OracleParameter objects in the heap on the next profiling, but it still seems to be the biggest chunk of occupied memory. What am I missing?

Comment: "I expected there to be a lot less OracleParameter objects in the heap on the next profiling" - why? Dispose != collect; disposing things is a good thing, but it has very little to do with the objects remaining on the heap

Comment: In the linked article, the `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` is before `Dispose()` is called on the individual parameters; you've done it the other way round. They also `Close()` and `Dispose()` the connection, which you don't show doing. No idea if either would make any difference.

Comment: Use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess instead of Oracle.DataAccess

Comment: @MarcGravell could you elaborate on that? What should I do to avoid the objects stalling in the heap? I might be missing some key info since I'm new to c# (came from c++).
MT0 I tried that as well. As mentioned, I tried doing it exactly like in the example, with the arrays and all the disposals and still no luck. The connection is disposed outside the function in question.
user10728126 thanks, I'll look into that!
TimSchmelter thank you, that's a good catch.

Comment: @A.Pet the first thing I'd ask here is: are you using server GC or desktop GC? note: desktop GC is *more aggressive*, as server GC assumes it can use more of the machine's memory; but: it isn't necessarily an error to use memory and not collect it immediately (you can use desktop GC on servers; I do exactly that for some service scenarios, where I want the service to use minimal memory; in fact, the "real time web-socket notification" stuff here on Stack Overflow does exactly that)

Comment: @MarcGravell since there are no parameters that say otherwise I'm going to assume that desktop GC, from what I get it's the default, isn't it?

Comment: @A.Pet it depends on your OS, the app kind, etc; there's no simple single answer to that question